# How to add Shortcode (font awesome) in widget title?

Tags: php, filters, shortcode, widgets

I want to show font awesome icon (installed) on the left side of the WordPress widget title. I found this shortcode that should do the work.

```
add_filter( 'widget_title', 'do_shortcode' );

add_shortcode( 'icon', 'shortcode_fa' );
function shortcode_fa($attr, $content ) {
return '<i class="fa fa-'. $content . '"></i>';
}
```

After adding this in `functions.php`, I should be able to add a gear icon in the widget title with below code from **Appearence>Widget**

```
[icon]cog[icon]
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your code in my install. It works, except that you made a typo (missing backslash):

```
[icon]cog[/icon]
```

Few notes:

- You must make sure to **enqueue** the *Font Awsesome* stylesheet.
- You must **close the shortcode**, like: `[icon]cog[/icon]`
- Remember to **escape** the class name with `esc_attr()`.
- Another shortcode idea: `[fa icon="cog"]`

Comment: I was just writing an answer, so I just append it to your answer, since you posted it before me ;-)

Comment: @birgire I especially agree with your fourth bullet.

Comment: @birgire  How would you make it to be like `[fa icon="cog"]`

Comment: @Pete I would suggest looking first at the [shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Full working code here!**

Add this to `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'widget_title', 'do_shortcode' );
add_shortcode( 'fa', 'shortcode_fa' );
function shortcode_fa($attr, $content ) {
    $icon = $attr['icon'];
    return "<i class='fa fa-$icon'></i>";
}
```

Add shortcode to widget title:

```
[fa icon=copyright] Widget title text
```

Result:

[image]